# How to download xcode dmg file?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6, dmg

I have an app which is working fine but recently I tried it on an iOS 6 device and it doesn't work and it seems it's because of my old xcode version (4.2). I tried to download xcode 4.6 dmg file from apple developer section. I have downloaded it twice but the weird thing is after it completes the download the xcode dmg file which is 1.4GBs on size changes to a login.html which is only 8kbs in size! anyone had any experience with these kinds of files? My internet connection isn't so speedy and this is tough for me to download these files over and over again.

Comment: "how download xcode dmg file?" - browser, `wget` or `curl`, etc., etc...

Comment: The current Xcode version is available in the Mac App Store. Why don't you download it from there?

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @flynx my internet connection is slow and it's easier for me to download the dmg file with a download manager

Comment: The mac app store doesn't work properly in China for example, so this question is highly relevant to people here.

Comment: my applestore is locked, so this question is really important. How to download (not get it thru the appstore)

Comment: https://github.com/iBcker/adcdownload

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-developer/44390183#44390183

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can download from here [https://developer.apple.com/downloads/](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#) but you have to authenticate with developers account.

You must **login** before download.

Comment: I have downloaded it from there , but when it completes it changes the dmg file into a login.html file . I download it using firefox and DownThemAll plugin

Comment: @m0j1 using download tools like that one will not help, as they normally having different sessions when accessing the server, you will need to download using the regular download from Firefox

Comment: I wish i knew about the direct download link yesterday. Updating xcode from app store is so slow.

Comment: Its really hectic to download 4gb XCode from India :( . more than 6times it stopped in middle after 80% .

Comment: The link for direct downloads has changed (regular download now tries to redirect you to AppStore): https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ (use search field on the left to find it faster) and use download manager in order to pause / resume / retry download if it fails.