# xcode : .dmg file not downloading using downloader

Tags: xcode, download, dmg, xcode10, xcode9.4

I want to download  `.dmg` file of current Xcode Tool. I have tried these : [how download xcode dmg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615251/how-download-xcode-dmg-file)  and [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file). after login successfully in apple account, folx downloader (I have installed in my Mac) automatically open with xcode link. When i click download now button it says unauthorized. Then I tried folx downloader and filled both  filed for authorized (user name and password) but same issue.

Please let me know how to download .dmg file using any downloader.

Comment: This link will worked for me !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon the same problem.
I managed to download XCode 7 using http://www.downthemall.net/ on Firefox