# Is there a way to just apply changes in iOS simulator without rebuilding the whole app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I'm asking because this is a feature of android studio and was wondering if xcode or an external thing had something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:
https://apps.apple.com/app/injectioniii/id1380446739 or from here https://github.com/johnno1962/injectionforxcode Also, I think you can get it through Alcatraz too if you have it on your XCode

Also, another tip if you have not made any changes and just want to attach the debugger and run the app without building you can do: CMD+Control+R which will run the app instantly without building.

Answer (score 1):

It's would be very useful feature for development, if the same would be possible with upcoming version.

But unfortunately, as of now, with current latest version of [Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675843/xcode-dmg-file-not-downloading-using-downloader/46887253#46887253), it is not possible to apply source code changes without rebuilding an application.

Nice question, it deserves space in Apple Bug Reporter...